# Running only Feature/Steps files with Behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I'm struggling to figure out how Behave works with Python. When I set up my files like this:

```
.
├── features
│   ├── tests.feature
│   └── steps
│       └── steps.py
└── mycode.py
```

and run Behave from the command line from the root directory of my code, it runs mycode.py first, then my features/steps. I want JUST my features/steps to run. I can do this by running Behave from the features folder, but then it can't find mycode.py to import the functions I want to test (imported using "from mycode import myFunction")

How do I run my tests without running my actual code, but still having it be accessable?

Answer (score 0):

What is exactl command you run the test ? I assume that you run "$behave" command in root directory and it should work.

How does "rootdirhere$behave" works: 
1. It will look for **features** directory by default. **features** is the folder where you put your all feature files. 
You can also specify another folder to hold all your feature files. 
eg: if you put them in my_feature_dir , you need to define the parameter **paths** in behave configuration file (.behaverc, behave.ini) *paths=my_feature_dir /.* 
2. Next, It will check if the **steps** folder is existed in **features** directory.
  steps folder is where you define all your steps. In step file , you will call methods in your code files, Page object for instance. in your case, step file call methods in mycode.py

So I don't see any problems here. It should work for you. 
Please share what command you run then i can help more.

Comment: I'm running Behave against the root, literally just "Behave" in the command line. It runs my program (it takes input from the command line, so it starts asking for input) and then runs my Features and Steps from the respective folders. It does run my tests all fine, I just don't want it to run my program as well. It seems Behave runs all Py files it can find

Comment: Absolutely No. behave does not run all .py files. What’s happen here is because the import command in step file. In step file, you do “from my_code import Myfunction”. It will run all code in that file. To avoid this, Please make sure my_code.py is an instance class and no method is defined outside Class. Create a class in my_code.py, Account Class for instance , use "from my_code import Account", in step call Account(context.driver).method_name(). only called methods are run.

Answer (score 0):

The functions in "mycode.py" files should be accesible from the "steps.py" file.

A relative import like

```
from .steps.py import xyz
```

should work